# User cannot get resource "services" in API group - Jenkins pipeline EKS deployment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-iam, kubectl, amazon-eks

I'm trying to deploy my docker image into the cluster using Jenkins. my Jenkins application is running in an EC2 ubuntu server. Initially, when I tried I was getting this error.

[image]

I referred to this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791303/kubectl-error-you-must-be-logged-in-to-the-server-unauthorized-when-accessing)
and added Jenkins users IAM arn to the Kube config file using

```
kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system
```

After updating the config file when I run my pipeline, I get this new error
[image]

My question is,

1. This Jenkins User is an admin user, then why am I getting this access control error?

Please help me with this?

Comment: The service account jenkins doesn't have privileges. Could you try to create a ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56439633/11977760)? There is [tutorial](https://medium.com/@pallavisengupta/jenkins-kubernetes-authentication-and-authorization-fa6966356c90) on medium about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment

The [service account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/) jenkins doesn't have privileges to list pods kube-system. You would have to create [ClusterRoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrolebinding-example) and [ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrole-example) to make it work.

You can do that with [kubectl create](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#kubectl-create-clusterrole) like in above @Gowtham Babu answer.

There is an example from below medium tutorial

> Also when rbac is set to true, following have to be done in order to allow jenkins pod access to “kube-system” namespace of the kubernetes cluster.
>
> Create a clusterrolebinding with permissions “cluster-admin”,

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding jenkinsrolebinding - -clusterrole=cluster-admin - - group=system:serviceaccounts:jenkins
```

Additional resources:

- https://medium.com/@pallavisengupta/jenkins-kubernetes-authentication-and-authorization-fa6966356c90
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @jakub. I was able to solve the error by creating a cluster binding role.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding NAME --clusterrole=NAME [--user=username] [--group=groupname] [--serviceaccount=namespace:serviceaccountname] [--dry-run=server|client|none]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue:

```sh
$ kubectl logs demo
panic: certificatesigningrequests.certificates.k8s.io "csr-xx9l9" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "certificatesigningrequests" in API group "certificates.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
```

To resolve it I did this by looking at answer from Gowtham Babu posted prior this post:

```sh
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding cesar3 \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --user=system:serviceaccount:default:default \
  --group=certificates.k8s.io
```